# Is Glass and Ceramic cookware suitable for high-heat frying and stir-frying?

Tags: food-safety, equipment

1. Is Glass and Ceramic cookware suitable for high-heat frying and stir-frying?
2. Can open flame (gas burner) make it shatter or crack?

Answer (score 5):

Speaking as a potter:

1. No.
2. Yes.

Stovetop glass and ceramic stovetop cookware are sold and used all over the world, and come in a variety of different types, including earthenware, flameware, stoneware, borosilicate glass, and high-temperature ceramic materials like vitrelle.  They have several advantages over metal cookware, primarily for slow, even cooking, like braises, stews, and oil-poaching.

All of them should be either heated slowly, or with a large quantity of liquid/food inside, to prevent them from heating too quickly or unevenly, which can cause them to crack.  Earthenware pottery like cazuelas are even soaked in cold water before heating.

This means that high-heat, empty-pan techniques like stir-frying or dry pan searing just aren't a good idea.  You can get glass and ceramic cookware up to high temperatures, but you need to make sure to get there slowly ... and also to cool off slowly.

References:

- [La Tienda's cazuela FAQ](https://www.tienda.com/learn-about-spain/how-to-cure-your-new-cazuela.html)
- [My Kitchen in Spain, Cazuelas](http://mykitcheninspain.blogspot.com/2010/01/clay-pot-cooking-cazuela-edition.html)
- [How
  to make sure your Pyrex doesn't shatter](https://www.epicurious.com/expert-advice/pyrex-glassware-safety-shatter-exploding-tips-article)
- [Tagine cooking tips](https://www.thespruceeats.com/how-to-use-a-moroccan-tagine-2394754)

Answer (score 3):

[Pyrex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrex) is the one people associate with oven-ware & is great in high heat, so long as the temperature change is slow & even...
But if you put it on a burner ring it will go off like a bomb!
[Believe me, I've seen it done a couple of times by accident.]

[Visions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visions_(cookware)), on the other hand, has such a low coefficient of expansion they even make frying pans out of it.

It's made of a material known as Calexium, which is

> a semi-crystalline ceramic having unique and useful properties such as
>   coefficient of thermal expansion so low as to be negative in
>   character, a true porosity of zero, and the unusual characteristic of
>   being transparent despite a substantial crystal content (often greater
>   than 75% by volume).
>
> Thanks to Calexium's extremely high thermal shock resistance, food can
>   be stored in the freezer in a piece of Visions and immediately taken
>   to the stovetop or oven for cooking.

Both are made by the same company, Corning, & both can be found in the same colours, so care must be taken to not confuse the two.

Visions takes longer to heat & cool than almost any other pan type, so you need to adjust your cooking style to accommodate that.
LeClair has [usage tips for Visions cookware](https://leclair.vision/Usage/)

Having said all that... personally, I'd stick with metal pans. Though Visions has a 10 year thermal shock guarantee, I'm still a little wary of it.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't believe the claims of Visions.  Maybe I'm biased because of Corning's prior generation of glass, on-the-stovetop cookware, which exploded on me while full of hot oil.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely to be suitable. Nearly all glass, and most ceramic, cookware isn't meant for for use over a flame at all (except possibly for keeping cooked food hot). But there is ceramic designed for use over a flame (Arcoflam is one brand). This should be heated gently to avoid the stresses caused by an uneven temperature, but can take very high heat. It's not really suitable for fast frying though, as it takes too long to cool down when you reduce the heat